# If $B$ is a $C^*$-subalgebra of $A$, do we have $AB= B?$

Tags: operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $B$ be a $C^*$-subalgebra of $A$. Do we have $AB= A?$ In other words, is $\text{span}\{ab \mid a \in A, b \in B\}$ norm-dense in $A$?

The usual way to approach these questions is by using approximate units, so that's how my attempt will go. Consider the canonical approximate unit of $A$, that is
$$(u_i)_{i \in I}$$
where $I$ is the set of all positive elements in the closed unit ball of $A$ and $u_i= i$.

Then if $a \in A$, we have $$a = \lim_i au_i$$

Now, consider the subnet $(u_j)_{j \in J}$ where $J$ is the set of all positive elements in the closed unit ball of $B$. Then we still have
$$a= \lim_j a u_j \in AB$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Have you tried $B=\{0\}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true.  Consider $A=M_2(\mathbb C)$, and
$$B=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}b&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}:b\in\mathbb C\right\}.$$
Note that
$$\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{21}&a_{22}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}b&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}b&0\\a_{21}b&0\end{bmatrix},$$
so clearly $AB$ cannot be all of $A$.

Comment: Where do I go wrong then?

Comment: The only thing that's wrong is the last thing you say,  that $a= \lim\limits_j a u_j$ for all $a\in A$.

Comment: But a subnet has the same limit?

Comment: Good point. There's more than one place you made a mistake:  the net $(u_j)_{j\in J}$ is in general not a subnet of $(U_i)_{i\in I}$, because it won't be cofinal.

Comment: You could even just take $A$ to be diagonal 2x2s.

Comment: @JPMcCarthy  That's true, and I considered examples along those lines, but in the end I wanted $A$ to be simple, or at least an example with $B$ not an ideal in $A$.